# This method is only available in managed mode

Tags: android, realm

I'm develop an Android app with Realm integrated and I have a problem when I try to search with a query. I try to search a product by its "id" into product list passed by parameter. This method worked perfect but suddenly I got the next exception:

```
Process: com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.ecommerceapp, PID: 9372
    io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: This method is only available in managed mode
            at io.realm.RealmList.where(RealmList.java:260)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.utility.UtilityDB.findProductIntoChildrenByEntityId(UtilityDB.java:176)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.fragment.ProductDetailFragment.setProductRealmToView(ProductDetailFragment.java:378)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.fragment.ProductDetailFragment.initializeEnvironment(ProductDetailFragment.java:119)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.fragment.ProductDetailFragment.onActivityCreated(ProductDetailFragment.java:96)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.fragment.ListsFragment.openProductDetailFragment(ListsFragment.java:256)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.fragment.ListsFragment$5.onClick(ListsFragment.java:193)
            at com.singularfactory.ecommerceapp.adapter.ListsContentAdapter.onClick(ListsContentAdapter.java:78)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My code:**

```
/**
     * Find a product into Children by entityId
     * @param products
     * @param entityId
     * @return
     */
    public static ProductRealm findProductIntoChildrenByEntityId(RealmList<ProductRealm> products, String entityId) {
        ProductRealm product = null;

        if(products != null) {
            **product = products.where()**  //The problem is here
                    .equalTo("entityId", entityId)
                    .findFirst();
        }

        return product;
    }
```

**My model:**

```
 @RealmClass
public class ProductRealm extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    private String  catId;                      //Only one category per product. In generic case many category per product
    private String  entityId;
    private String  parentId;
    private String  typeId;                     //"simple" | "configurable"
    private String  sku;
    private String  canaryProduct;
    private String  premium;
    private String  brand;
    private String  dinitosQty;
    private String  name;
    private String  ean;
    private String  description;
    private String  shortDescription;
    private String  weight;
    private String  isSaleable;
    private String  imageUrl;
    private String  unit;
    private String  unitFresh;
    private String  childrenSelected;
    private String  manageStock;
    private float   price;
    private float   minWeight;
    private float   quantityWeight;
    private int     quantity;
    private int     stock;
    private int     typeOfAttribute;            //0: Per units | 1: Per weight | 2: Both
    private int     typeOfChildrenSelected;     //0: Per units | 2: Per weight | -1: Undefined
    private boolean isIntoShoppingCart;         //Flag to indicate if the product is into the Shopping Cart
    private RealmList<AttributeRealm> attributeItems;
    private RealmList<ProductRealm>   children;
    ...
    /* Getters & Setters */
```

I hope that the question is well detailed.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the `RealmList` you are providing to the `findProductIntoChildrenByEntityId` method is a standalone one, meaning, not managed by Realm. A standalone `RealmList` only lives in memory (and not in Realm), which means that it's not possible to query on it.

Comment: And the solution is make this with single "for"? Or how can I provide a RealmList valid?

Comment: You get the managed version of the list simply using the getter `getChildren()` for example

Answer (score 0):

Your `public static ProductRealm findProductIntoChildrenByEntityId(RealmList<ProductRealm> products, String entityId) {` realmList you provide here must be bound to an existing, open realm instance. The query would run in Realm, and it would run if the objects within the `RealmList` are copied to Realm.