# How to convert realm list to RealmResults<Object>?

Tags: android, realm

I wanted to query on realm list as:

`City cityObj = realmCitylist.where().equalTo("name", strCity).findFirst();`

but error run time occurs as:

> UnsupportedOperationException: This method is only available in managed mode

So, i googled and find this question with answer: [This method is only available in managed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429239/this-method-is-only-available-in-managed-mode), which suggested that it's not possible to query on realm list.

So i have to query on `RealmResults` as:

`RealmResults< City > realmCities;

City cityObj = realmCities.where().equalTo("name", strCity).findFirst();`

**Question:** **How can i convert reamList to RealmResults?**

Answer (score 1):

> This method is only available in managed mode

This means that you can only use this method if it belongs to a `RealmList` inside a managed RealmObject.

So this doesn't work:

```
RealmList<Blah> blahs = new RealmList<>();
blahs.where()... // <-- this is an unmanaged list, this won't work
```

Solution: if you want to query on top of a RealmList, it should belong to a managed RealmObject, returned by a Realm instance.

```
RealmList<Blah> blahs = realm.where(Doh.class).findFirst().getBlahs();
RealmResults<Blah> blahResults = blahs.where().equalTo(BlahFields.NAME, strCity).findAll();
```

---

In your case, you probably just want to execute a RealmQuery towards a Realm instance in the first place.

```
RealmResults<City> cities = realm.where(City.class).findAll();
City city = cities.where().equalTo(CityFields.NAME, strCity).findFirst();
```